# Reading in date column if first row isn't a date with SSIS Excel Data Source

Tags: ssis

I am trying to read in an excel worksheet that has a date column. It appears that SSIS is treating the column as a number column since the first row is empty.

Here are the Excel columns:

[image]

When I preview it inside of ssis Excel source editor it shows:

[image]

You can see my TermDate column is showing up as numbers and not a date.  Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If at all possible have the data sent as anything other than an Excel file. SSIS and Excel do not play well together. A .csv will work better than an Excel file, if you can't get a true .txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Excel's storage of dates.  http://www.debugging.com/bug/19252  I ended up using this function in C# app to switch from the numeric date to a datetime date.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Seriously?  For the loss
    /// <see cref="http://www.debugging.com/bug/19252"></see>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="excelDate">Number of days since 1900-01-01</param>
    /// <returns>The converted days to date</returns>
    public static DateTime ConvertXlsdtToDateTime(int excelDate)
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(1899, 12, 31);

        // adjust for 29 Feb 1900 which Excel considers a valid date
        if (excelDate >= 60)
        {
            excelDate--;
        }

        return dt.AddDays(excelDate);
    }
```

You can either use that formula in a script transformation to generate a DateTime value or use an ugly expression to do the same. It's late so I'm assuming your dates are after the fake 1900-02-29 as mentioned above

`DATEADD("day",TermDate - 1,(DT_DATE)"1899-12-31")`

Below is an example using your input data, the above expression in a derived column to generate `ExcelDate`. I carried the `TermDateAsDate` to ensure I was matching dates as expected.

[image]