# SSIS Using Derived column to reference column from same table

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I am trying to import an xls spreadsheet into a table, and one of the columns needs to be derived from a different column in the same table. I would like to do this during the import phase rather then creating a SQL Task to do it after the import. I am horrible when it comes to creating expressions in SSIS, so this is probably an easy task - but I just can't get it right.

```
DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,columndata)+1,0))
```

That is the expression that I am trying to use.

Comment: What is the input and what is the expected output?  You appear to be trying to get the last second of the current month.

Comment: I'm trying to get the last day of the month from the date in the column

Answer (score 0):

You want the following:

```
DATEADD("S",-1,DATEADD("M",DATEDIFF("M", (DT_DATE) 0,DATEADD("D",[dataDate],(DT_DATE)-2))+1,(DT_DATE)0) )
```

1) You need to use " to surround your dateparts.

2) You need to cast your 0 date to an explicit date type.

This expression takes the column dateserial number [dataDate] adds that number of days  to the date -2

```
DATEADD("D",[dataDate],(DT_DATE)-2)
```

(apparently sql day 0 and excel day 0 are different by 2 days on my versions (sql2008r2 and excel 2007)) and finds the number of months from date 0 to that date,

```
DATEDIFF("M", (DT_DATE) 0,DATEADD("D",[dataDate],(DT_DATE)-2))
```

then adds 1 to that number of months and adds it back to date 0

```
DATEADD("M",DATEDIFF("M", (DT_DATE) 0,DATEADD("D",[dataDate],(DT_DATE)-2))+1,(DT_DATE)0)
```

(to get the beginning of the next month following the column date value),  Then it subtracts 1 second from the date to get the last second of the month of the column date value in the datetime format.

```
DATEADD("S",-1,DATEADD("M",DATEDIFF("M", (DT_DATE) 0,DATEADD("D",[dataDate],(DT_DATE)-2))+1,(DT_DATE)0) )
```

Comment: Cool when I get into work on Monday I will make some tweaks and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: That didn't work. The error says Datediff does not support data type DT_R8 for parameter number 3

Comment: I had missed that this was from Excel at first. What is the format of your data column in the source data?  It appears to be coming into SSIS as a Float.  See answer and comments here for possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085928/reading-in-date-column-if-first-row-isnt-a-date-with-ssis-excel-data-source

Comment: Just worked out how to use the dateserial number from sql in the expression

Comment: I'm still having issues making it work. I think I am just going to use a SQL Task to update the table after it is import. I have other post processing that needs to be done anyway.

Comment: I kept getting errors some I posted above and I don't have time to go through each one. I have other projects waiting on this one to be finished. It's working now as a SQL Task