# SSIS Number to Date

Tags: ssis

I wonder whether there is some function in SSIS I do not know about that can convert `number` to `date` just like in Excel when you convert e.g. number `41640` to `1/1/2014`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading in date column if first row isn't a date with SSIS Excel Data Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085928/reading-in-date-column-if-first-row-isnt-a-date-with-ssis-excel-data-source)

Comment: Not really duplicate. I am not going to load data from Excel or so. But that code in C# looks interesting. I will give it a try. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Derived Column Task with the following code, just change your fields etc..

(DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,8)[IntNumberDateField],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,8)[IntNumberDateField],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,8)[IntNumberDateField],7,2))

Answer (score 0):

Because in SQL Server, the default starting point of date is '12/30/1899', therefore as you can see in SSMS, DATEDIFF(DAY,'1899-12-30','2014-01-01') gives you 41640.

If you want to implement it in SSIS, you can use Execute SQL Task with parameter binding, and use DATEADD function.

Source: DATEADD function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx